# Using CreateInstance for class in different project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reflection

I have a solution with 3 projects. In project1 when I refer to a class in the ***local*** project CreateInstance works fine.

```
Dim oo As New Object = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("TestClass", True)
oo.TestSub()
```

But when it's in one of other projects it returns "Nothing".

```
Dim oo As New Object = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Project2.Business.TestClass", True)
oo.TestSub()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Types are stored per assembly (usually a project).  GetExecutingAssembly always refers to the assembly that the currently executing code is a part of.  If you want to create an instance of a type froma  different assembly you will need a reference to THAT assembly, or call GetExecutingAssembly from inside that assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are stored per assembly (usually a project). GetExecutingAssembly always refers to the assembly that the currently executing code is a part of. If you want to create an instance of a type froma different assembly you will need a reference to THAT assembly, or call GetExecutingAssembly from inside that assembly.

You can use 'Assembly.Load' to get a reference to an assembly (even if it is already loaded) and call '.CreateInstance' on that.